# How to create a table similar to another table without copying the data at creation?

Tags: mysql, datatables, rdbms

I have a table `books`, I want to create table `Book101` and then copy the contents of table `books` into it.

Comment: I am puzzled by the differing requirement in the title and question - to copy or not to copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Book101 AS SELECT * FROM books WHERE 1=0;
```

Above example will create only structure.

If you want to Clone the table with structure and data both then you can you below one:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Book101 AS SELECT * FROM books;
```